# Authentication with Github in Asp Net Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, oauth

I want to add Authentication with GitHub to my Asp Net Core 6 project, but everything I find in the Internet is for older versions of Asp Net. How can I add it?

I added the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth` package to my project and created an Github OAuth application. I also added the client id and client secret with

```
dotnet user-secrets set Github:ClientId <clientid>
dotnet user-secrets set Github:ClientSecret <clientsecret>
```

I searched for tutorials online, but there are only tutorials using a Asp Net Version that is less than 6.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us what you have tried and describe the issues you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `AspNet.AspNet.Security.OAuth.GitHub` and `OctoKit` library. You need run the install command in your project path. Like:

```
PM> cd .\GithubAuth
PM> Install-Package AspNet.Security.OAuth.GitHub -Version 6.0.5
PM> Install-Package Octokit -Version 0.50.0
```

I have test in my dotnet core 6 app, and it works fine.

**For more details, please check below blogs:**

In this blogs, it mentions Linux platform, you can ignore it.

[Add GitHub OpenID Auth For ASP.NET Core Apps](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/github-openid-auth-aspnet-core-apps)

Comment: But in the tutorial there are using Startup.cs. I have a Program.cs. My Knowlegde is that they changed that in Asp Net 6. The structure is totally different too.

Comment: @CheckerPhil Don't worry.  Sample code in .net 5, like `services
        .AddAuthentication...`

Comment: @CheckerPhil In .net6, you can write your code like : `builder.Service.AddAuthentication....`

Comment: I just copied the Startup.cs that was provided in the Github project of the link in my Program.cs and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is the instructions from *External OAuth authentication providers* for `ASP.NET Core 7.0`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/other-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Register a new OAuth application here:

https://github.com/settings/applications/new

If you want your organisation to own it then use this guide instead:

https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/creating-an-oauth-app

Docs for Authorizing OAuth Apps

https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps

Microsofts documentation says:

> Third-party NuGet packages, such as the ones maintained by
> aspnet-contrib, can be used to complement the authentication providers
> implemented by the ASP.NET Core team

This is their NuGet:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OAuth.GitHub

If you receive the error `Unable to unprotect the message.State.` check that your CallbackPath is unique if you have several OIDC connections.

You can then add this code:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddGitHub(options =>
    {
        options.ClientSecret = "<ClientSecret>";
        options.ClientId = "<ClientId>";
        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc-github";
    })
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

Github SSO will then look like this:

[image]

If you want the GitHub users email the code should look like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddGitHub(options =>
    {
        options.ClientSecret = "<ClientSecret>";
        options.ClientId = "<ClientId>";
        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc-github";
        options.Scope.Add("user:email");
    })
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

[image]

https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps

Comment: For those using Asp.Net 7 I've have a 'Hello World' web app on [GitHub](https://github.com/codybartfast/hello-github-oauth) demonstrating OAuth with GitHub

Comment: codybartfast's example really helps - note in particular you need to also turn on cookie auth otherwise the github auth code will stack overflow, the cookie is needed for persistence - see https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/issues/782